# Roslyn CodeFix with multiple variants to fix

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a CodeFix provider, purpose of which to inject service to current class, like add new private field, parameter to constructor, assignment statement in constructor, using ServiceNamespace, and use of this field in proper place(s).
At some point, I have a name of this service, and I need to find namespace for this service to add correct using. I'm doing this via `compilation.GetSymbolsWithName(typeName)`, but this method can return several matched symbols from different namespaces/assemblies. 
So, the question: is there any way I can show this variants to user so he can decide the correct type?

Comment: For each diagnostic, you can add more than one fix.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, so I need to determine different namespaces variants _before_ register of codeFix actions. And this works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @PauloMorgado 
I have another question. 
I have calls like `MyServiceProxy.DoJob()` where MyServiceProxy is static class. I am changing MyServiceProxy calls to newly injected service call `myService.DoJob()` (I want to call injected service instead of static class). But what if I have same situation in different areas of code and I have several variants of fix (with different namespaces), and want to change all of them with concrete namespace variant in file/folder/project/solution, what should I do?

Comment: If I understand this right, it's should be done with custom FixAll provider, because each of fix may add new property/constructor parameter/assignment statement in constructor, and all of this changes will have collisions with each other, and BatchFixer will not resolve this.
Am I right?

Comment: You better ask another question and close this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each diagnostic, you can add more than one fix.